# How to disable a layer in a Tilemap's collision mask via code?

Tags: physics, tilemap, godot-4, layers

I have a tilemap in Godot 4.1 and I have defined a physics layer for a tileset, but I cannot figure out how
to disable a layer in collision mask in code.

I already found out that I should get tileset first and I used this code to set a collision mask to interact with player:

```
tileset.set_physics_layer_collision_mask(0,2)
```

But the problem is I don't know how to disable it?

Comment: Maybe setting mask to a different one from the player could do the same trick? Or removing the whole layer with [`remove_physics_layer(int layer_index)`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tileset.html#class-tileset-method-remove-physics-layer).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set an empty mask.

Here you are setting the mask of the layer 0 to the value 2 (which has only one bit set):

```
tileset.set_physics_layer_collision_mask(0,2)
```

Similarly, you can set it 0 so no bit is set:

```
tileset.set_physics_layer_collision_mask(0,0)
```

Or you could set some other value if you need to.